# Calling python script from c#, unexpected token 'from' error

Tags: c#, python

Trying to get started using IronPython in Visual Studio.  Created a C# winforms app to run a python script.  Get the "unexpected token 'from' error".  The python script contains a single line of code:

```
import numpy as np
```

That's it.  I can't make sense of the error.  I tried a print statement which was OK, but any import throws the "from" error.

Here is the C# code:

```
var py = Python.CreateEngine();
String main = <my anaconda3 directory> ;
String dir = String.Empty;
ICollection<String> paths = py.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(dir);
dir = main + @"\Lib\site-packages";
paths.Add(dir);
dir = main + @"\Lib";
paths.Add(dir);
py.SetSearchPaths(paths);
py.ExecuteFile("Test.py");
MessageBox.Show("Done");
```

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Turns out it is the incompatibility between Python 2 and Anaconda 3.  Used the correct library (Anaconda 2) and got a different error.  Apparently there are issues with numpy and IronPython but that is not the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incompatibilities between Python libraries.  Be sure to reference the right one if you have both.